# Counts of duplicate rows as a new column without grouping of duplicate rows

Tags: r, duplicates

My data looks like this one:

```
   A     B     C
1  a     1     ff
2  b     1     re
3  c     1     sd
5  a     2     as
6  c     4     fe
7  d     5     tt
8  d     5     tt
9  d     9     oi
```

I want to add a new column D, which will contain how many times an element from the column A is repeated in all data, like this:

```
   A     B     C   D
1  a     1     ff  2
2  b     1     re  1
3  c     1     sd  2
5  a     2     as  2
6  c     4     fe  2
7  d     5     tt  3
8  d     5     tt  3
9  d     9     oi  3
```

I don't want to simplify my data grouping raws like in this thread:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/270481.html

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `table`:

```
data <- read.table(text='A B C
a 1 ff
b 1 re
c 1 sd
a 2 as
c 4 fe
d 5 tt
d 5 tt
d 9 oi', header=T)

data$D <- table(data$A)[data$A]
```

Answer (score 3):

Untested code, but something along these lines should work -

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,D := .N, by = 'A']
```